# .dropna() increases memory usage

Tags: python, pandas

First I import the whole file and get a memory consumption of 1002.0+ KB

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="./dataset/chicago.csv"
)
print(df.info())

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 32063 entries, 0 to 32062
# Data columns (total 4 columns):
# Name                      32062 non-null object
# Position Title            32062 non-null object
# Department                32062 non-null object
# Employee Annual Salary    32062 non-null object
# dtypes: object(4)
# memory usage: 1002.0+ KB
# None
```

then I drop NaN, run the script again and get a memory consumption of 1.2+ MB

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="./dataset/chicago.csv"
).dropna(how="all")

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# Int64Index: 32062 entries, 0 to 32061
# Data columns (total 4 columns):
# Name                      32062 non-null object
# Position Title            32062 non-null object
# Department                32062 non-null object
# Employee Annual Salary    32062 non-null object
# dtypes: object(4)
# memory usage: 1.2+ MB
# None
```

since I'm dropping one row I would expect that memory consumption goes down or at least remain the same no this.

Does any body know why is this happening? or how to fix it? or if this is a bug?

**EDIT:** [chicago.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jtG37fiO6W7AIw_69CXn8bKfIpjDd7oVjIseu20mm_A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your index changed. Before it was a `RangeIndex` which worked because you just needed the start and stop values. Now since you dropped one row, you have an `Int64Index`, which takes more memory. Try adding a `.reset_index()` at the end (I'm not sure, but it may convert the index back to a range).

Comment: you only dropped one row so really it shouldnt make much of a difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change comes from the fact that your index changed from a `RangeIndex` to an `Int64Index`, which takes more memory.

You can "fix" this by resetting the index after the `dropna()`, but this will have the side effect of changing the row index (which you may not care about).

Here is an illustrative example:

First create a sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10000)})
df.loc[1000, "a"] = None
```

Print the info:

```
print(df.info())
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#a    9999 non-null float64
#dtypes: float64(1)
#memory usage: 78.2 KB
```

Drop the na values:

```
print(df.dropna().info())
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#Int64Index: 9999 entries, 0 to 9999
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#a    9999 non-null float64
#dtypes: float64(1)
#memory usage: 156.2 KB
```

Reset (and drop) the index:

```
df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True).info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 9999 entries, 0 to 9998
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#a    9999 non-null float64
#dtypes: float64(1)
#memory usage: 78.2 KB
```

Comment: This is a really insightful answer!

Comment: Awesome answer and excellent information.  Thanks @pault.  I learned something here. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pault, but what If I care about the index? let's say I have:

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer="./dataset/chicago.csv",
    index_col="Name"
)

Comment: @juanp_1982 is it still a `RangeIndex`? Are you still seeing the memory increase in that case? Can you edit your question to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @pault: I asked without testing it (I thought I did). I just re-run my script again with the index_col and the it behave as I expected, the memory consumption went down. I just learned another reason of setting an index in the dataframe AND I didn't need .reset_index()

Answer (score -2):

This is not a bug. It is working as intended, you are loading the file in so it is taking that amount of memory as before but more because you are then searching through the dataframe and removing the rows that have NaN which adds memory usage.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about it? please I don't understand why "removing the rows that have NaN which adds memory usage."

Comment: because you load in all the data first and then the rows get removed. they aren't done at the same time.